# Can't push to array from Presentational Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components:
1. The smart component - contains an array and fills it with data
2. The presentational component - display the data from first component that is received using

```
  @Input() usersList: UsersList;
```

In the 2. component I can view all of the list items

```
    this.usersList.users.forEach(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Now, for example, I am in 2. component .ts file and I want to add usersList.users Array to myNewArray

```
  addToArray() {
    this.usersList.users.forEach(data => {
        this.myNewArray.push(data);
    });
  }
```

Instead of items being added to the array, I am getting an error:

```
UsersTableComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Of course I have defined myNewArray and usersList is also defined in component 1.

Comment: Looks like you trying to push to an array in component2 when you have defined it in component1...

Comment: @Nicholas K yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. There must be a way to make this work?

Comment: You need to use an `EventEmitter` to *emit* the value back to the other component. The approach you are trying simply won't work coz component2 doesn't know about it.